# Can I consecutively fade-in divs using a loop?

Tags: jquery

I have a few divs I want to show consecutively.  I tried:

```
var divs = ["#masterhead", ".links", ".code", ".projects", ".self"]
var fade_time = 1000;
var pause_time = 500;
for(var i = 0; i <= divs.length; i = i + 1)
{
    setTimeout( divs[i].fadeIn(fade_time) , 500) ;
}
```

I tried that because I wanted shorter code as opposed to (which works the way I want it to):

```
    function A()
    {
        jQuery("#masterhead").fadeIn(fade_time);
        setTimeout(B, 500);
    }
    function B(){
        jQuery(".links").fadeIn(fade_time);
        setTimeout(C, 500);
    }

    function C(){
        jQuery(".code").fadeIn(fade_time);
        setTimeout(D, 500);
    }
    function D(){
        jQuery(".projects").fadeIn(fade_time);
        setTimeout(E, 500);
    }

    function E(){
        jQuery(".self").fadeIn(fade_time);
    }   
    A();
```

So, what am I doing wrong in the shorter code?

Comment: You realise that `divs[i]` is just a string, and not an HTML element or DOM node?

Comment: I actually considered that, but I'm new and really didn't know what I'd search for in order to rectify that.

Comment: Could you show a (small) [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), that reproduces your problem/page?

Comment: It appears someone already answered the question below. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simpler way to do it that doesn't use `setTimeout()` at all; jQuery's [`.delay()` method](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) is clearer for this purpose:

```
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i = i + 1)
{
    $(divs[i]).delay(pause_time * i).fadeIn(fade_time);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sK99B/

Four problems with your code:

- `divs[i]` contains the selector as a string, so you need to use `$(divs[i])` to get a jQuery object that you can call `.fadeIn()` on.
- `setTimeout()` expects a function as its first parameter. You are trying to call a function directly. You can fix this by wrapping it in an anonymous function.
- `setTimeout()` doesn't pause execution, it queues up a function to run later, so because all your timeouts are set to 500 they'll all be queued up to run at (virtually) the same time.
- The condition in your `for` should use `<`, not `<=`.

Try:

```
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i = i + 1)
{
    (function(i){
       setTimeout( function() { $(divs[i]).fadeIn(fade_time); }, pause_time * i);
    })(i);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sK99B/1/

Note that if the function passed to `setTimeout()` uses the loop counter `i` you'll have a problem that because the functions aren't run until after the loop finishes they'll all try to use the final value of `i` - so you need to introduce a closure, which makes this method even messier.

Comment: All of the answers work, but I'm glad you explained it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use the callback.

```
var divs = ["#masterhead", ".links", ".code", ".projects", ".self"]
var fade_time = 1000;
var pause_time = 500;
var i = 0;
function startDisplay() {
  i = 0;
  showNext();
}
// just use this function as a callback, each time, to display the next
function showNext() {
  if (!divs[i]) {
    // dernière div
    return
  }

  setTimeout(function () {
    // you can hide the previous one, for example
    //$(divs[i-1]).hide();
    // take the current div, increment it
    $(divs[i++])
      // fade it in, and use the current function as callback
      .fadeIn(fade_time, showNext);
  }, pause_time);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
for(var i = 0; i <= divs.length; i = i + 1){
  setTimeout( function(){ 
       $(divs[i]).fadeIn(fade_time);
   } , 500 + (i*pause_time)) ;
}
```

Comment: This will call `.fadeIn()` immediately and pass its return value to `setTimeout()`...